# Can SQL Server tell you what paths it has found when it can't create a foreign key?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to introduce a foreign key with ON DELETE SET NULL into a database with a complex schema.

The script I'm using has this command (names changed):

```
ALTER TABLE a
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_a_b
        FOREIGN KEY (b_id) 
        REFERENCES b (b_id)
            ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

When I run this script I get the following error message:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_a_b' on table 'b' may cause
>   cycles or multiple cascade paths.

I can't see what the multiple paths are, is there some way I can get SQL Server to list them?

Answer (score 0):

You can check dependencies as outlined here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190624.aspx

When you use the T-SQL  as shown, you get only one level, but if you use SSMS, it will cascade down multiple levels.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in functionality just for that purpose. I suppose that with recursive CTE you could write a query on `sys.foreign_keys` and couple of other system views, that would list cascade paths.

But simplest solution is to do that with Database Diagrams. Start by adding the table that's not letting you add the constraint, then right click and select "Add Related Tables". Then select all the tables and add related tables again, and so on. To keep the diagram clean, in the process unselect or remove tables that you know are not part of the problem.
After you're done, you'll be able to see cycles/multi cascades: they will be chains of 1-N (direcion matters) or 1-1 relations starting and ending on the same table, or leading from one table to another through different paths.

You could use code similar to below to exlude tables that don't have any FK constraints with update/delete actions other than NO_ACTION (0). Building on that you could also exlude tables with only one FK constraint of this type.

```
select
    object_name(parent_object_id),
    *
from sys.foreign_keys fk
where 1=2
    or delete_referential_action <> 0 
    or update_referential_action <> 0
```

I know it may be time-consuming especially for big databases, and you have to know your db well, but that's my best shot for now :).